# How to calculate arrival time of packet?

Tags: sockets, node.js

I would like to know, how I can calculate the arrival time of a packet sended from the client.
I have try to send a timestamp (milliseconds since 1970) with the packet and then calculate it like this on the server.

> timestamp_on_server - timestamp_from_packet

But the problem with this, is that I also get negative numbers and that isn't correct.

So how do I do this the right way? :-)

Thanks!

Comment: The arrival time is the current clock time. Your calculation calculates the *transmission* time. Which is it that you want?

Comment: Ohh sorry. My english isn't that good. But yes, its the transmission time :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not work when machines are not properly synchronized to a time source (see [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)).

But in general, it's not the greatest idea to rely on the time sampled on different nodes. What you can do instead is measure the [**round-trip times**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay_time) (packet sent there and reflected back with sender's timestamp intact), so you only ever work with the same time source.

Side note: clock on the same machine can still jump back if forcefully adjusted by some privileged process, so it's probably a good idea to ignore (and maybe log) negative RTT values.

Comment: Round-trip, is that like a echo? Server sends a packet to client, and client sent it straight back. And then server calculate the time in between?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Could also be the client that initiates the exchange.